# Is there a way to export pub/priv key from java keystore and import to gpg keyring

Tags: code-signing, gnupg, jks

I'm wondering if there is away to export pub/priv key from java keystore(digicert signed) in format which then can be imported to gpg(.asc) keyring. I tried using openssl to extract keys in pem however the same can't be imported in gpg and I don't see any commands in openssl which can convert pem to .asc.
I might be completely off track and gpg might not be compatible with pem. Any directions on same will be appreciated.